# Hide custom post type and use its slug in new plugin menu

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I want to use custom post type in my web app and want to use that url in my plugin menu. I have created custom post type like this.

```
register_post_type( 'reserve',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Reserves' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Reserve' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Reserves' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add Reserve' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Reserve' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit'),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Reserve' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Reserve'),
            'view' => __( 'View Reserve'),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Reserve'),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Reserves'),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Reserves found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Reserves found in trash' ),
            'parent' => __( 'Parent Reserve')
        ),      

    'description' => __( 'This is where you can add new Reserves' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => false,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'reserves', 'with_front' => false ),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'excerpt',/*, 'page-attributes'*/ ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true
    )
);
```

Notice that I have set show_ui as false so that my new custom type wont be displayed on admin sidebar. Now I am creating a my plugin menu as following.

```
$topslug = 'reserve/admin'; 
add_menu_page('Reserve Overview', 'Reservation', 'view_reservation_plugin', $topslug, 'show_start_page',RESERVE_URL.'images/menu_icon.png');
add_submenu_page($topslug, 'RESERVE', 'Reserve Builder', 'view_reservation_plugin', 'reserve/manage_reserve', 'show_manage_reserves');
```

From above code you can find that I have created a menu as Reservation having two submenus 1) Reserve Overview 2) Reserve Builder.

Now my issue is I want to change my URL of Reserve Builder.

Currently its 
    'admin.php?page=reserve/manage_reserves'. 
I want to change it like
    'edit.php?post_type=reserve'
so that i can use wordpress inbuilt facility.

Say if I am passing 
    'edit.php?post_type=reserve' 
in 
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=reserve', 'RESERVE', 'Reserve Builder', 'view_reservation_plugin', 'reserve/manage_reserve', 'show_manage_reserves').Menu gets disappeared. TIA.

Comment: Why not just remove `'show_ui' => false` and use it? Add submenu pages to that post type and you can use the built-in WP editor, meta boxes for customization, etc.

Comment: Actually I don't want to make two menus in my custom plugin. All menu should go under one main tab.

Comment: You _can_ add submenu pages to custom post types with [`add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page). I have done it with many plugins I've developed. For Custom Post Types: `add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=your_post_type',...)`.. Or am I understanding it wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `edit.php?post_type=reserve` as first parameter and that should be parent menu slug. Instead pass it as `menu_slug` parameter, see code snippet below.

```
add_submenu_page( 
    'reserve/admin', 
    'Reserve',
    'Reserve Builder', 
    'view_reservation_plugin', // $capability
    'edit.php?post_type=reserve' 
);
```

Comment: You are life saver....

Comment: Actually I have tried in this manner but i dnt know wht was my mistake anyways you are awesome..